# Bootstrap SelectPicker duplicates select lists on initialization

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

After dynamically creating select lists using javascript by cloning html, and after the select list creation, the attempt to initialize the select lists using `$(MySelectList).selectPicker();` seems to succed but also after calling `.selectPicker()` it seems to duplicate several of the selects.

Without the `.selectPicker()` call, there are three drop down lists in the cloned row, but you can not change the values (the lists do open, but selections don't take the values).

After calling `.selectPicker()`, the new row's drop downs take selected values, but there are now 5 total select lists. Two additional lists which are dup's.

This is really all there is to it:

```
 <div id="advSearchRows" class="clearfix">

    <!-- Form Row Template -->

    <div class="row clone" id="ASR1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="selectpicker include">
                <option>Must Include</option>
                <option>Must NOT Include</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="selectpicker match">
                <option id="-1">foo</option>
                <option id="0">bar</option>
                <option id="1">fubar!</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="search-text form-control" placeholder="Keyword Text">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group remove hidden"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

And the row duplicate code

```
var numRows = $("#advSearchRows .clone").length;        // how many rows currently
    var lastRow = $("#advSearchRows .clone:last");          // the last row in the list
    var lastId = lastRow.attr("id").replace("ASR", "");     // the id of the last item
    if(numRows < 5) { // duplicate (clone) template row:     
        var id = parseInt(lastId) + 1;                      // the numeric id of the new row
        var newRow = lastRow.clone().attr("id", id);        // actual cloned row
        newRow.find("select.include")
            .attr("id", "include" + id)
            .selectpicker(); // include ddl id
        newRow.find("select.match")
            .attr("id", "match" + id)
            .selectpicker();     // match ddl id
        newRow.insertAfter("div.clone:last").slideDown('slow');
        $("#" + id).find(".remove").removeClass("hidden");
```

I wonder if there is something wrong with my selector...  `newRow.find("select.match").attr("id", "match" + id).selectpicker()` but it looks proper according to the documentation... maybe there is something I am missing.

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I found the solution. Basically I needed a hidden template that was not initialized, clone the template, and then initialize. Easy Peasy.

```
//
// Handle "Add" row button event:

function cloneRow() {
    var numRows = $("#advSearchRows .clone").length;
    var lastRow = $("#advSearchRows .clone:last");
    var template = $("#advSearchRows #ASR1");
    if (numRows >= 6) return false;
    var id = parseInt(lastRow.attr("id").replace("ASR", "")) + 1;
    var newRow = template.clone().removeClass("hidden").attr("id", id);
    newRow.find("select.include").attr("id", "include" + id).selectpicker();
    newRow.find("select.match").attr("id", "match" + id).selectpicker();
    newRow.insertAfter("div.clone:last").slideDown('slow');                
    $("#" + id).find(".remove").removeClass("hidden");
    return false;
}
```